# Finding base for subspace of cubic polynomials with vanishing integrals

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, polynomials

$U \leq P_3(\mathbb{R}), \\ U = \{P_3(\mathbb{R}) : \int_{-1}^{1}p = 0 \} $

How do I find a base for this subspace? I know how to do that for when the condition for $U$ is having a specific root for $p(x)$. For example $U = \{P_3(\mathbb{R}) : p(6) = 0\}$. We can write the constant in the polynomial using the other coefficients and substitute then write the polynomials as a linear transformation of the coefficients.

My intuition is that $p(x)$ is odd so it has to have the following form: $p(x) = a_1x^3 + a_2x$.

In this example, I write down the integrated function and substitute the upper and lower bounds (-1 and 1) and the only thing I get is $c = \frac{-a}{2}$ for $p(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$. I don't know where to go from there. All I know is that I should probably somehow write $p(x)$ as a linear transformation that includes $x^3$ and $x$.

Comment: If $f$ is odd then $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)dx=0$. But in your space there is also some $g$ even such that   $\int_{-1}^1 g(x)dx=0$.

Comment: You have a three dimensional subspace of a four dimensional vector space. $p(x)\in \{x,x^3\}$ are certainly linear independent vectors in $U$. Hence we only need a third vector $p(x)=a+bx^2$ with $\int_{-1}^1 p(x)\,dx = 0$ which is easy to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f \in U$ and $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$
$\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)\mathrm{d}x = \frac{a}{4}x^4 + \frac{b}{3}x^3 + \frac{c}{2}x^2 + dx \ \Big|_{-1}^{1}$
$ = (\frac{a}{4} + \frac{b}{3} + \frac{c}{2} + d) - (\frac{a}{4} - \frac{b}{3} + \frac{c}{2} - d)$
$\rightarrow b = -3d$

Hence:
$f(x) = ax^3 + (-3d)x^2 + cx + d\\ 
= a(x^3) + d(1 - 3x^2) + c(x)$

So we can write every member of $U$ as a linear combination of $B = \{x^3, 1 - 3x^2, x \}$ therefore, $B$ generates $U$. $B$ is also clearly linearly independent so $B$ is a basis for $U$.